# RxJava - Kotlin: Throttle the stream for same type of events

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, throttling

I have an array of integers `a = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1 , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2]`
Assume that each integer is emitted after a gap of 100ms

How is it possible to make sure that there is a gap of atleast **500ms**  between same integers being emitted. Ignore the element if same element was emitted less than 500ms ago.

For example: in above case, the result should look like

```
1,2,3,4,5,7,1,2
```

Comment: if i got correct: you have some `Observable` that emits some integer every 100ms. In that case you can use operator `yourIntegerObservable.scan(listOf(), {list, newItem -> list.plus(newItem)})` it will return you `Observable<List<Int>>`, after that you can `.map` it to analyse what is the distance between same items...